# Stop debug stalling in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-jdt

I recently installed eclipse on my Mac pro.  I had previously been using eclipse on my mac book.  When I run an app engine project on the mac book, it works fine.  When I run it on my mac pro it brings me into the debugger where I have to click resume a few times but then everything works well again.  I went looking into the debug settings and many other settings pages but everything looks the same.  I don't remember making any changes to my mac book settings.  The code is an exact copy on both machines.  What am I missing here? What settings do I need to change.

Stack trace at the first stall:

```
Thread [2039077@qtp-7797531-0] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
Transformer.isRuntimeCode(ProtectionDomain) line: 154   
Transformer.transform(ClassLoader, String, Class<?>, ProtectionDomain, byte[]) line: 81 
TransformerManager.transform(ClassLoader, String, Class, ProtectionDomain, byte[]) line: 122    
InstrumentationImpl.transform(ClassLoader, String, Class, ProtectionDomain, byte[]) line: 155   
Proxy.defineClass0(ClassLoader, String, byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]   
Proxy.getProxyClass(ClassLoader, Class<?>...) line: 504 
ClearCast$CasterImpl<S,T>.constructProxy() line: 349    
ClearCast$CasterImpl<S,T>.<init>(Class<S>, Class<T>, Options) line: 313 
ClearCast.compileCaster(Class<S>, Class<T>, Options) line: 219  
ClearCast.cast(S, Class<T>, Options) line: 231  
ClearCast.cast(S, Class<T>) line: 241   
Runtime.<clinit>() line: 32 
FinalizableReferenceQueue.<init>() line: 106    
Interners$WeakInterner<E>.<clinit>() line: 124  
Interners.newWeakInterner() line: 66    
ProtocolSupport.<clinit>() line: 55 
UserServicePb$CreateLoginURLRequest$1(UserServicePb$CreateLoginURLRequest).<init>() line: 259   
UserServicePb$CreateLoginURLRequest$1.<init>() line: 610    
UserServicePb$CreateLoginURLRequest.<clinit>() line: 610    
UserServiceImpl.createLoginURL(String, String, String, Set<String>) line: 54    
UserServiceImpl.createLoginURL(String) line: 42 
login.jsp line: 20  
login_jsp(HttpJspBase).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 97    
login_jsp(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717   
JspServletWrapper.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean) line: 377   
PrivilegedJspServlet(JspServlet).serviceJspFile(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, String, Throwable, boolean) line: 313  
PrivilegedJspServlet(JspServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 260 
PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 23 
PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run() line: 59   
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
PrivilegedJspServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 57  
PrivilegedJspServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717    
ServletHolder.handle(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 511 
ServletHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 390   
SecurityHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 216  
SessionHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 182   
DevAppEngineWebAppContext(ContextHandler).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 765    
DevAppEngineWebAppContext(WebAppContext).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 418 
DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 70 
Dispatcher.include(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 192   
JspRuntimeLibrary.include(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, String, JspWriter, boolean) line: 968    
mainHeader.jsp line: 57 
feed_jsp(HttpJspBase).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 97 
feed_jsp(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717    
JspServletWrapper.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean) line: 377   
PrivilegedJspServlet(JspServlet).serviceJspFile(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, String, Throwable, boolean) line: 313  
PrivilegedJspServlet(JspServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 260 
PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 23 
PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run() line: 59   
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
PrivilegedJspServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 57  
PrivilegedJspServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717    
ServletHolder.handle(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 511 
ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1166 
ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 58 
ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 43    
ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
StaticFileFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 122   
ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
ServletHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 388   
SecurityHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 216  
SessionHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 182   
DevAppEngineWebAppContext(ContextHandler).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 765    
DevAppEngineWebAppContext(WebAppContext).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 418 
DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 70 
JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler(HandlerWrapper).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 152    
JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 349    
Server(HandlerWrapper).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 152   
Server.handle(HttpConnection) line: 326 
HttpConnection.handleRequest() line: 542    
HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete() line: 923    
HttpParser.parseNext() line: 547    
HttpParser.parseAvailable() line: 212   
HttpConnection.handle() line: 404   
SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorEndPoint(SelectChannelEndPoint).run() line: 409 
QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run() line: 582
```

Comment: This happens one time when I start up the app and launch the page in a web browser.  I then have to click resume 3-4 times and then it works fine until i restart the app

Comment: I reinstalled Eclipse a few times and it seems to have stopped doing this.  No idea what was causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a breakpoint set to stop automatically when an exception is thrown.  Several exceptions are thrown in the process of starting up.  To see if this is what's happening, open the Breakpoints window.